# How to divide a total value of 1 between x variables with a biased weighting

Tags: java, math

I'm tasked with a problem that I'm not quite sure how to solve mathematically.

I am trying to create a method that takes an int array as an argument. the length of the array will vary but will never be zero. The values in the array are not important as the method will overwrite them with the values determined below.

The purpose of the method is to divide a total of 1.0 between each position in the array. This is straightforward enough however an additional complexity is that the division should be biased. The values on the left should be higher than the values on the right (see example output below).

An example would be passing an int array of size 7. I would expect an output similar to:

> [.3, .25, .15, .1, .09, .07, 0.04]

where the sum of all the values = 1

I'm using Java but even pseudo code will help!

Comment: For 7 positions, divide by 8, then first position is 2*1/8 and all other positions are 1/8

Comment: This would only make the first value biased. I need all of them to be different, highest on the left and lowest on the right

Comment: You didn't specify that in your question

Comment: Also do the values have to be random?

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify. The values are random as long as the sum of them all equals 1

Comment: Biased how? Just different than the original, or biased in a certain way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd generate a list of unique random numbers, then normalize it by dividing all of them by their sum.

Then sort and reverse your list.

```
int n = 7;

// make a list of n unique random numbers 
double[] randomValues = new Random().doubles(0, 1).distinct().limit(n).toArray();

// normalize the list and reverse sort it
double sum = Arrays.stream(randomValues).sum();
List<Double> array = Arrays.stream(randomValues).boxed()
        .map(d -> d/sum)
        .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Your array should now have random values adding up to 1, sorted in reverse order

Caveat:

You might want to actually recalculate the latest value by subtracting the other ones from 1 to minimize rounding errors. It depends on the precision you require. 
If you need exact values, you can't work with doubles, work with ints instead (like we do with currencies).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify eactly what bias you are looking for or what distribution, but a straightforward aprroach for a biased non-uniform distribution would be:

Draw the first number `a1` from `[0,1]`, draw the second number `a2` from `[0,1-a1]`, draw the third number `a3` from `[0,1-a1-a2]` and so on. set `an` as the complement to `1` of the current total, and sort everything at the end.

Comment: How about taking the sum of the array elements, and divide each element by it?

Comment: That would give you the uniform distribution. Where's the bias? only the order?

Answer (score 1):

```
double[] distributeDecreasing(int n) {
    Random random = new Random();
    double[] values = new double[n];
    final double nEps = 0.0001 * n;
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++n) {
        double value = nEps + random.next();
        sum += value;
        values[i] = value;
    }
    double sumFrom1 = 0.0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++n) {
        values[i] /= sum;
        sumFrom1 += values[i];
    }
    if (n > 0) {
        values[0] = 1.0 - sumFrom1;
    }
    Arrays.sort(values, Comparator.reverseOrder());
    return values;
}
```

- The biasing done by decreasing order.
- The sum 1.0 realised by dividing of the sum of Random.next (between 0 and 1),
  plus an epsilon to not be zero.
- For minimal floating point error, correct the first element as 1.0 - sum of the rest.